# Event Listener not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jsp

Im trying to register a onClick event Listener to every dynamically created img element. When im trying to pass argument to the eventHandler function , the event gets fired or the handler function gets called when page loads and it does not work after that but it works fine when i don't pass argument to the event handler function

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            try {
                if (this.response.contentlength != 0) {
                    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    var imageUrl = urlCreator
                            .createObjectURL(this.response);
                    var elem = document.createElement("img");
                    elem.setAttribute("style","width:100%");
                    elem.setAttribute("src", imageUrl);
                    elem.addEventListener("click",on);
                // here elem.addEventListener("click",on(elem));
                    parent.appendChild(elem);
                }
            } catch (Exception) {
            }
        };
        request.send();
    }

    //for overlay effect
    //function on(ele){
    function on(){  
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display="block";   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Alternately, if you want to pass arguments.. please refer the below code

```js
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            try {
                if (this.response.contentlength != 0) {
                    var urlCreator = window.URL ||        window.webkitURL;
                    var imageUrl = urlCreator
                            .createObjectURL(this.response);
                    var elem = document.createElement("img");
                    elem.setAttribute("style","width:100%");
                    elem.setAttribute("src", imageUrl);
                    // here you should pass your arguments.. you cannot directly call the listener funciton. It always has to be wrapped with anonymous function.
                    var yourdata = "xxxx";

                    elem.addEventListener("click", function(){on(yourdata)});
                // here elem.addEventListener("click",on(elem));
                    parent.appendChild(elem);
                }
            } catch (Exception) {
            }
        };
        request.send();
    }

    //for overlay effect
    //function on(ele){
    // the listener function always takes event as first parameter and event has the information about from which element this listener is called
    function on(evt, data){  
        var targ = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display="block";   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            try {
                if (this.response.contentlength != 0) {
                    var urlCreator = window.URL ||        window.webkitURL;
                    var imageUrl = urlCreator
                            .createObjectURL(this.response);
                    var elem = document.createElement("img");
                    elem.setAttribute("style","width:100%");
                    elem.setAttribute("src", imageUrl);
                    //
                    elem.addEventListener("click",on);
                // here elem.addEventListener("click",on(elem));
                    parent.appendChild(elem);
                }
            } catch (Exception) {
            }
        };
        request.send();
    }

    //for overlay effect
    //function on(ele){
    // the listener function always takes event as first parameter and event has the information about from which element this listener is called
    function on(evt){  
        var targ = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display="block";   
    }
```

Comment: thanks that worked but what if i want to send some other information(some argument) to the event handler function.

Comment: you could add it as custom attributes to the element as 'data-attrName = "xxxx"' in element and access the value in targ.getAttribute('data-attrName')